# Java. Object being repeatedly created using a timer. Is there a way to reduce one of the variables everytime the timer executes

Tags: java, timertask

I'm creating a battery object that's  being created on a timer. I'm feeding the output of this into a database

Its basically just a simulator for a front end that monitors a battery device. And emits errors when the variables drop below a certain value

So far I'm creating the object every 10 seconds as follows.

```
public class Battery {
public String name;
public int input;
public int output;
public static int charge;

Random random = new Random();

public Battery(String dName) {
    this.name = dName;
    this.input = random.nextInt((415 - 400) + 1) + 400;
    this.output = input + random.nextInt((3 - 0) + 1);           
}



   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Battery [name=" + name + ", input=" + input + ", output=" + output + ", charge=" + charge + "]";
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Battery battery = new Battery("Battery 1");
           
            System.out.println(battery.toString());
        }
    } , 0, 1000);// end of timer
}
```

I have a variable charge which will represent the battery charge. I've tried to make this decrease using a while loop.

```
battery.setCharge(100);
                int charge = battery.getCharge();
                System.out.println(charge);
                while (charge>0) {
                    System.out.println(charge);//for testing
                    battery.setCharge(charge);
                    charge--;
                }
```

But because of the nature of the timer, its just the same object being created every time. So in this case it just counted down from 100 then output the charge as 1.

Is there a way to decrease this every time the timer is called? I've tried using a static integer but that didn't help at all.

I also tried to put the while loop outside of the public void run() method and got a myriad of errors for doing that!

Still in the learning phase of Java, this possible needs to go down the threads route. but I'm not quite there yet.

Also I have purposely not added a means for the timer to end, Its just something I'm turning on and off in eclipse to watch numbers appear on my front end.

Apologies if adding a second question isn't allow, but is there a way to make

```
 this.input = random.nextInt((415 - 400) + 1) + 400;
```

return a 0 every so often?

Comment: Fixing your code formatting might help us help you.

Comment: @Basil Bourque any advice on what to fix? I usually just let it auto format with ctrl +I

Comment: Start with the indenting of the second code sample.